# wso2 - how to get TLS certificate details in sequence

Tags: wso2

In my integration scenario I need to veryfy some data of TLS certificate.
Is there a way to get details of TLS certificate (eg. subject name) in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do that in wso2. In any of wso2 scopes (Axis2/Axis2-Client/Transport/Operation/Synapse), you don't have access / information to used TLS certificate in request.
Some workaround, could be use reverse proxy, for example HAProxy to add information in request header, like described here: [SSL Client Certificate Information in HTTP Headers](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/ssl-client-certificate-information-in-http-headers-and-logs/) and read in sequence from header. In nginix I belive that is also possible.

Last way, I think, is to modify source code, or implement own TransportReceiver for https requests.